# JQuery exclude certain HTML rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table that is structured as seen below. It is populated with results from a MySQL query.

```
<div class="timecard">
<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="display_row odd">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">2400-Orchard</td>
            <td align="right">9:47am</td>
            <td align="right">5/19/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">01:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="display_even row">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">Out</td>
            <td align="right">12:37am</td>
            <td align="right">5/17/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">0:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="display_odd row">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">1200-Duffy's</td>
            <td align="right">12:37am</td>
            <td align="right">5/17/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">2:00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

And a javascript jquery that runs through the table and totals up the results of the individual "job_code" clock ins. However, it is also including the "Out" clock in with a total of "NaN." Is it possible to exclude this from the printed or .appended results? Below is the JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();
var components = timeString.split(':');
var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
total += hrs;

var temp = [];
$('.job_code').each(function (index, element) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    temp.push(text);
});

// remove duplicates
var job_code = [];
$.each(temp, function (index, element) {
    if ($.inArray(element, job_code) === -1) job_code.push(element);
});

var sum = {};
$.each(job_code, function (index, element) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.job_code:contains(' + element + ')').each(function (key, value) {
        var timeString = $(this).siblings('td.hrs').text();
        var components = timeString.split(':');
        var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
        var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
        total += hrs;
        sum[index] = {
            'job_code': element,
                'total': total
        };
    });
});

console.log(sum);

$.each(sum, function (index, element) {
    $('#total').append('<p>Total for ' + element.job_code + ': ' + element.total + '</p>');
});

});
```

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2D5fb/2/

Comment: Test whether `text != "Out"` before pushing it onto `temp`?

Comment: I've got an javascript error on line 7 (`total += hrs;`). Replace it with `var total = hrs;` and the DOM-Element `#total` is not in DOM. Try `$('.timecard_list').after('<p>...</p>');` then it run's. http://jsfiddle.net/Mgc9S/

Comment: @algorhythm please see this fiddle. I had an error in my HTML at first. http://jsfiddle.net/2D5fb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7P37/) of your code tidied up by adding the

```
</table> and </div> end tags, which seem to have resolved the NaN issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I had to edit the `temp` section of the code to look like this.

```
var temp = [];
$('.job_code').each(function (index, element) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text != 'Out') {
        temp.push(text);
    }
});
```

Here is also a link to the jsFiddle that shows it working. http://jsfiddle.net/2D5fb/3/

Special thanks to @Barmar, your comment got me on track.